# How does boost link libs?

Tags: c++, boost, static-linking, dynamic-linking

As I understand I must link additional libraries or not using boost and it depends on some modules require them or they are just independent templates/macros.

For instance using boost/thread.hpp I must link boost_thread and boost_system.

1. So if I link them dynamically I need to have boost on target platform or just add them to the final application (same or not directory)?

2.If I don't want any dependencies I can link them statically, however the size of the application will grow by size of whole library or just by part of it I've used?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Q1. Yes or no. If you're in Windows, the shared library (.dll) can be in system directory or local directory (which the program is). If you're in linux, the shared library (.so) must be in `LD_LIBRARY_PATH`.

Q2. No, the program's size doesn't grow by size of *whole* library. If your linker isn't crazy, he will select necessary object of library and link the program against only them.

Comment: On Windows, the DLL can be anywhere within PATH, even if it's neither the system nor the local directory.

Comment: About Q1: So regardless of the platform, we need somewhere in the system these dynamic libs from boost, otherwise the application will not execute? If yes, is it better practise (in case of boost) to link it static if we want to have portable application (in same architecture)?

Comment: @AdamAdamowicz Yes. Maybe you have seen errors such as XXX.dll or YYY.so is missing. But static linking does not make the program portable. Each platform has its own ways (e.g. binary format, API, filesystem, etc...), and you must follow this.

Comment: Yes I understand, I meant 'portable' on same platform and architecture but independent on installed libs in the system.

Comment: @AdamAdamowicz then, you should use static library - I hardly use shared library because of that point >o<